# Can't focus on object before it is hidden (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have this `input` that when focused opens up a `select`.

The behavior I want could be achieved with a simple `select` but I wish to further add functionalities that a simple `select` does not allow. Simply put when you have the 'box' focused, you can view the options, when you don't you cannot.

I tried to implement this logic using a state that checks if the parent `div` where the `select` and the `input` is focused.
Clicking the input displays the options as expected, however when I try to select an option from the list, before I can select it, the `select` gets hidden and I can't choose anything.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-bouman-9i1hjv?file=/src/App.js)

Is there another approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is that another focusable element (the `select`) receives focus. You can't avoid that, but you can change how you react to that: you need to check whether the element causing the blur is a descendant of your div. If it is, you don't need to close your select box.

Change your `onBlur` handler to this:

```
const onBlur = ({ currentTarget, relatedTarget }) => {
    if (!currentTarget.contains(relatedTarget)) {
        setMenuActive(false);
    }
};
```

[Forked demo.](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-pond-tdv08g?file=/src/expression_input.js) Note that I also changed your state to a simple boolean instead of an object.